# Is it possible to use vue.js with wagtail stream-fields without using DRF?

Tags: django, vue.js, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

is it possible to use vue.js with wagtail stream-fields without using DRF? I would like to use wagtail and vue.js without going the headless route. So is it possible to use vue.js as part of wagtail's stream-field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The notes from my DjangoCon US workshop may be helpful:

https://wagtail.io/headless-workshop

But please note that the Vue.js examples are intended to demonstrate the concepts as simply as possible - it's not an example of best practice Vue code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but I would like to know if it's possible to use Vue.js without going the headless route and if it works with wagtail's stream-field.